# no signal at all after amdgpu-pro install

Tags: drivers, radeon

i've installed the drivers on this page

https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Radeon-Software-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

my system was running slower than when i had windows 10 so i tried this, but after install and reboot (i followed the instruction page on amd site, so i just did
./amdgpu-install -y
i got boot info, violet screen, then lost signal.

i tried entering recovery mode but the power in the house went down so i had to start up the pc again. this time no signal at all.
i triedd changing videocard with the integrated one (vga) still nothing. i tried disconnecting the hard disk and the radeon, after some time the pc booted from the usb drive. i tried reconnecting the hard disk and after some tries i was able to get the system working but incredibly laggy. i logged in and uninstalled the amd drivers. after the reboot everything was smoother, so i tried reconnecting the radeon via DVI, and it finally woerked again.

now 2 questions:
what happened?
did i do something wrong with the installation, and can i use the radeon drivers or should i stick with the open source ones?

as i said, the system is slow (even dragging windows isn't smooth)

here are my specs:

Processor       : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5000+
Memory      : 4039MB (2966MB used)
Machine Type        : Desktop
Operating System        : Ubuntu 17.10

-Display-
Resolution      : 1280x1024 pixels
OpenGL Renderer     : AMD BONAIRE (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-32-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
X11 Vendor      : The X.Org Foundation

thanks!

Comment: forgot to say: i'm using a sapphire radeon r7 260x

Comment: I have two monitors and one of them lost signal after I instaled  the AMD driver, my card its also a r7260x